# Why is the identity permutation in $A_n$?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, symmetric-groups

I just have small question about the proof. In order to show that $A_{n}\leq S_{n}$ one has to (among other things) show that the identity element $\varepsilon$ in $S_{n}$ is also the identity element in $A_{n}$. Now, when I'm reading of the notes from my professor he just writes

> Identity: Clear, since $\varepsilon =\bigl( 1 2 \bigr)\bigl( 2 1 \bigr)$.

I dont understand what he means when he writes this. I would instead argue that $\varepsilon \in S_{n}$ is always an even permutation since it can be written as $0$ transpositions and $0$ is even. Thus $\varepsilon\in A_{n}$. Is this a valid argument?

Comment: Your proof is much better because it deals with the cases $n=0,1$ as well.

Answer (score 3):

Both answers are fine. I think that your justification is the better one, but you have to admit that, indeed, $\varepsilon=(1\ \ 2)(2\ \ 1)$ and that this equality also proves that $\varepsilon\in A_n$. Also, some beginners may find it hard to understand the idea that $\varepsilon$ is the composition of $0$ transpositions.

Comment: I'm not sure I see why $\varepsilon = (12)(21)$ would show that $\varepsilon \in A_{n}$. I can see that $\varepsilon$ is written as an even number of transpositions but I seem to have forgotten why $\varepsilon = (12)(21)$. I would probably write the identity element in $S_{2}$ as $0$ transpositions or $\varepsilon = (11)(22)$  but the last representation I believe is redundant.

Comment: Do you know what $(1\ \ 2)$ *means*? It's the map that maps $1$ into $2$, maps $2$ into $1$ and maps each  element of $\{3,4,\ldots,n\}$ into itself. It is actually equal to $(2\ \ 1)$. And if you compute the composition of these two maps, what you get is the identity map.